# How to pipe to git tag command?

Tags: git, unix, pipe

This is what I try.

`echo "v1.2.3" | git tag`

Does not work. Is it just not possible? Have also tried `|git tag -`

Comment: Are you trying to specify the name of the tag or the comment?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you need to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag name must be specified as an argument, but you can use the `xargs` utility to do this:

```
echo "v1.2.3" | xargs git tag
xargs -n 1 git tag < file-with-list-of-tags-to-make.txt
```

Comment: You need to specify `-n 1` if you have multiple tags otherwise xargs would pass all arguments to git tag once